# Symfony2 - Set a selected value for the entity field

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, selected

I'm trying to set a selected value inside an entity field. In accordance with many discussions I've seen about this topic, I tried to set the `data` option but this doesn't select any of the values by default:

```
class EventType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('place', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'RoyalMovePhotoBundle:Place',
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_value' => "Choisissez un club",
                'mapped' => false,
                'property_path' => false,
                'data' => 2
            ))
            ->add('begin')
            ->add('end')
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

By looking for more I've found that some people had to deactivate the form mapping to the entity. That seems logical so I tried to add `'mapped' => false` to the options, without success...

If it can help, here's my controller:

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function addAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $event = new Event();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EventType(), $event);

        $formHandler = new EventHandler($form, $request, $em);

        if($formHandler->process()) {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "L'évènement a bien été ajouté.");
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('photo_event_list'));
        }

        return $this->render('RoyalMovePhotoBundle:Event:add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

And the `EventHandler` class:

```
class EventHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
    public function process()
    {
        $form = $this->form;
        $request = $this->request;

        if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if($form->isValid()) {
                $this->onSuccess($form->getData());
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function onSuccess($entity)
    {
        $em = $this->em;

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

I'm a bit stuck right now, is there anyone who got an idea?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You only need set the data of your field:

```
    
    class EventController extends Controller
    {
        // ...

        public function addAction()
        {
           $request = $this->getRequest();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $event = new Event();
            $form = $this->createForm(new EventType(), $event);

            // -------------------------------------------
            // Suppose you have a place entity..
            $form->get('place')->setData($place);
            // That's all..
            // -------------------------------------------

            $formHandler = new EventHandler($form, $request, $em);

            if($formHandler->process()) {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "L'évènement a bien été ajouté.");
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('photo_event_list'));
            }

            return $this->render('RoyalMovePhotoBundle:Event:add.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't really remember but I think I've already tried this before, without success. Well, I will accept this as a response since I can't try your solution at the moment (I'm not working on this project anymore), It seems to be the more logical way.

Answer (score 7):

In order to option appear selected in the form, you should set corresponding value to entity itself.

```
$place = $repository->find(2);
$entity->setPlace($place);
$form = $this->createForm(new SomeFormType(), $entity);
....
```

Comment: Actually, sorry for first comment, it does work it was an error on my side!

Comment: In fact, I already did this but forgot to mention it in the question. I've edited it. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

For **`non-mapped`** entity choice fields, the method I found easiest was using the [`choice_attr`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-attr) option with a `callable`. This will iterate over the collection of choices and allow you to add custom attributes based on your conditions and works with expanded, multiple, and custom attribute options.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('place', 'entity', array(
            //...
            'choice_attr' => function($place) {
                $attr = [];
                if ($place->getId() === 2) {
                    $attr['selected'] = 'selected';
                    //for expanded use $attr['checked'] = 'checked';
                 }
                 return $attr;
            }
       ))
       //...
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `query_builder` option, and the `data` option expects an collection instance, and you **don't** want to touch your controller by adding `setDatas` for only certain fields, and you already have your querybuilder and the ids of the repopulating options in your form type class, you can repopulate a selection as following:

```
// Querybuilder instance with filtered selectable options
$entities = $qb_all; 
// Querybuilder instance filtered by repopulating options (those that must be marked as selected)
$entities_selected = $qb_filtered;
```

Then in your add() Method

```
'data' => $entities_selected->getQuery()->getResult(), // Repopulation
'query_builder' => $entities,
```

**EDIT: Real use case example**

You want to repopulate a checkbox group rendered with following elements:

`Label: What is your favourite meal?`

`4 Checkboxes: Pasta, Pizza, Spaghetti, Steak`

And you want to repopulate 2 Checkboxes:

`Pizza, Steak`

`$qb_all` would be a QueryBuilder instance with the all 4 selectable Checkboxes

`$qb_filtered` would be a new additional QueryBuilder instance with the repopulating Checkboxes `Pizza, Steak`. So a "filtered" version of the previous one.

Comment: Please explain this better.  What is `$qb_all` and what is `$qb_filtered` in a real use case?

Comment: @bought777 I added an EDIT to my post. Its more clear now?