# Assigning a default value to a oneToMany association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a basic Symfony2/Doctrine2 question. I have two entities the first called "Column" that has OneToMany issues, entity "Issue". And the Issue entity has a ManyToOne relationship with the entity Column. When I create a new Issue I wish to assign a default value for the column.

If I create a hidden field in IssueType.php and assigned a default value I cannot save the submitted form because I get an error about assigning a string to setColumn and not an instance of the Column entity as defined in my Issue entity (see below).

```
public function setColumn(\WebConfection\ServiceDeskBundle\Entity\Column $column)
{
    $this->column = $column;

    return $this;
}
```

Can anybody please advise on the best way to accomplish this? I have read a few articles but am a tad confused and not sure which way to jump. An idiot friendly answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I may get it wrong but doesn't this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752115/symfony2-set-a-selected-value-for-the-entity-field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a hidden field for this to work. Just set the right (default) Column on the Issue you want to add within your action,

```
// ...
$issue = new Issue();
$issue->setColumn($yourDefaultColumn);

$form = $this->createForm('your_issue_form', $issue);
// ...
```